# new DateTime throws exception in IE 11 but not Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following line in the code behind:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month),   Convert.ToInt32(day), 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

where year = "2013" month="11" day="11"

When I debug it in IE it throws a System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Works fine in Chrome.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

Okay I'm at my wits end. I've created a new web forms project and added the following method to the code behind. I am calling it in the Page_Load event with the following string 
"‎11‎/‎11‎/‎2013‎ ‎00‎:‎00‎:‎00" and it throws a System.FormatException at line "int month = Convert.ToInt32(monthString.Trim());" the value of monthString is "11". This is only happening in IE11 and runs fine in Chrome and IE10.

```
private DateTime getDateTimeFromTimeArgument(string argument)
        {
            string[] argumentArray = argument.Split(' ');
            string[] valuesArray = argumentArray[0].Split('/');

            string yearString = valuesArray[2];
            string monthString = valuesArray[1];
            string dayString = valuesArray[0];

            int month = Convert.ToInt32(monthString.Trim());
            int day = Convert.ToInt32(dayString.Trim());
            int year = Convert.ToInt32(yearString.Trim());

            DateTime dte = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            return dte;
        }
```

Comment: This seems like C# that is executed on server side - how is it related to browser? Where exactly FormatException is thrown? What are the values for year, month and day variables?

Comment: Your browser makes no difference to anything in codebehind, but it's possible that they're sending different requests (if this code is run in response to a `POST`, for example). How are the values `year`, `month` and `day` set?

Comment: Actually, since he hasn't said where `year`, etc. come from, we can't rule out browser involvement somehow. Hey, @crazyvan, help us rule out browser involvement.

Comment: Yes the FormatException is thrown at this line on the server side. year, month, day are string with the following values: "2013", "11", "11"

Comment: Try `new DateTime(2013, 11, 11)` and see if that fails.

Comment: You have 3 possibilities to FormatException: `Convert.ToInt32(year)`, `Convert.ToInt32(month)` and `Convert.ToInt32(day)`. Eg if you have `Convert.ToInt32("ac")` the exception is thrown

Comment: Look inside the Request from IE11 and Google Chrome to see what has been sent to server.

Comment: try day.Trim(), year.trim() etc etc

Comment: @giammin : i agree with you...as year may look 2013 but can contain spaces, so before converting to int it is always good to Trim the values.

Comment: FormatException was thrown at Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month), Convert.ToInt32(day).

Comment: But why does it fail to convert "2013" "11" "11" to Int32?

Comment: @crazyvan: Try : `Convert.ToInt32(year.Trim())` , `Convert.ToInt32(month.Trim())` , `Convert.ToInt32(day.Trim())`

Comment: Guys, Convert.ToInt32(" 2013  ") does not throw an exception!

Comment: Thanks you all for doing the heavy lifting on this one! indeed, @wannadream 's answer got it done.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing a similar issue and one thing I did notice is that when you try and parse the date string into a character array there appears to be some (hidden)characters with unicode 8206 in IE11 but not Chrome. In my case I am picking up the date client side from a telerik RadDatePicker control and passing it to another page. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is two years old BUT the answer is IE for some reason has a bunch of hidden non valid characters in there so you have to parse them out using something like:

```
    valToUse = new string(val.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c) || c == '/').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Date string sent by IE 11 contains hidden char 8206 which causes converting issue.[image]

Workaround:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(new string(this.AssignedDate.Where(c => c != '\u200E').ToArray()));
```

Really don't understand why Microsoft created a mine for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting code this way:

```
Trace.WriteLine("Year + " + year);
var yearValue = Convert.ToInt32(year);
Trace.WriteLine("Month + " + month);
var monthValue = Convert.ToInt32(month);
Trace.WriteLine("Day + " + day);
var dayValue = Convert.ToInt32(day);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(yearValue, monthValue, dayValue, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

And see the output window and exception

Answer (score 0):

IE11 does some weird stuff with how it encodes dates.

try using

```
date.toJSON()
```

on the browser

so your query string looks like

```
?dateArg=2013-12-14T20:37:03.121Z
```

on the server you can use the date like so

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateArg); //will parse the json into a C# object

var day = date.Day; //get day

var year = date.Year; //get year

var month = date.Month;  //get month
```